# Mock context manager inside a class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, contextmanager

I have the below context manager inside a class method, which I would like to mock for unit testing.

```
def load_yaml_config(self) -> dict:
    """
    Load the config based on the arguments provided.

    Returns: dict
        dictionary which will be used for configuring the logger, handlers, etc.
    """

    with open(self.yaml_path, 'r') as config_yaml:
        return yaml.safe_load(config_yaml.read())
```

How could I achieve it?

EDIT:

As @chepner suggested (I can't accept his/her answer since it was via comment), the best way to go seems to be by using the unittest's mock_open functionality.

This way, I can simply go:

```
import unittest.mock as um

with um.patch('builtins.open', um.mock_open(read_data=YAML_TEST)):
    h = MyClass.load_yaml_config()
```

Comment: Two options: patch `open`, or write a temp file with test data and point `yaml_path` to it.  I'd probably go with the latter, personally, because it's easier to write test data to a file than to mock out a file object.

Comment: @Samwise could you please post it in an answer so I can understand the concept more easily?

Comment: That's your IDE throwing the warning, not Python itself. You can ignore it, or use https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open.

Comment: What do you want the test to actually test?  Your `mocked_yaml` test function doesn't even call your `load_yaml_config` function.  Are you trying to test `load_yaml_config`, `yaml.safe_load`, both, neither...?

Comment: I would like to test just load_yaml_config. @Samwise

Comment: What do you want to test that it does?  If you're mocking out `yaml.safe_load` and `open` there's not really anything left to test.  Like I said way back when, the better (and easier!) way to test this than doing a bunch of funky patching would be to just give it a real file and verify that it loads it correctly.

Comment: I would like to avoid dependence on external yml file and test that just by passing a string to the function, yaml reads it correctly.

Comment: The function doesn't even take a string argument.

Comment: @Samwise yeah, that is where I should probably start. How can I add that to the function? Apologies for the newbie question, I'm looking for best practices.

Comment: Trying to unit test this code might be premature if you're still learning about how to define functions.

Comment: @Samwise not learning how to define functions (I obviously know how to pass arguments and so on), it's more of how to inject the string for the file in my function,

Comment: Add a parameter to the function, pass it as the argument.  There's not any special magic to it.

Comment: @Samwise but the arguments to open are (path, 'r') whereas a string would be just one. It may sound silly, but there is where I'm stuck.

Comment: @chepner your comment about using mock_open was the solution I ultimately went with. Not sure if you would like to post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to refactor this code to be able to test the `safe_load` part without having to actually `open` a file *or* patch `builtins.open`, you could do:

```
def load_yaml_config(self) -> dict:
    """
    Load the config based on the arguments provided.

    Returns: dict
        dictionary which will be used for configuring the logger, handlers, etc.
    """

    with open(self.yaml_path, 'r') as config_yaml:
        return self._load_yaml_config(config_yaml.read())

def _load_yaml_config(self, yaml_text: str) -> dict:
    return yaml.safe_load(yaml_text)
```

and then in your test:

```
TEST_YAML_DATA = """
stuff:
  other_stuff
"""

def test_load_yaml_config():
    assert WhateverMyClassIs()._load_yaml_config(TEST_YAML_DATA) == {
        'stuff': 'other_stuff'
    }
```

Modify to use actual appropriate YAML formatting and the correct expected dict output.

Note that all this is really testing is `yaml.safe_load` (which should have its own unit tests already) and the fact that your code calls it.  Other than a typo in a variable name (which is easier to catch with a linter or static type analyzer), it's hard to imagine what type of bug this test might catch/prevent.

Practically speaking I probably wouldn't bother covering this function in a unit test at all, but would instead try to have some sort of larger integration test (using a real file) that involved loading a config as part of some larger test scenario.

Answer (score 1):

### The easy way

Just create the appropriate yaml file in your testing code. But you probably don't want that, since you're making this post.

### A hack with mocking

You can override `open` with your mock in the module scope:

```py
# test_YourClass.py

builtin_open = open

class open:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        pass
    def read(self):
        return 'hardcoded file contents for testing'

# Test here

open = builtin_open
```

This code is just a general idea, I haven't run it. It might require some additional work, such as parameterizing the mock file contents.

### Dependency injection

The "proper" way is to unhardcode `open()` call in the class and inject your context manager, I suppose. It's up to you. I personally don't like injecting everything just for the purpose of unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was not able to follow you on the last part: dependency injection. How could I unhardcode that open()? PS: could please take a look at the edit I just posted?

Comment: Basically, you just reject responsibility for opening the file yourself. `load_yaml_config` takes a file-like object as an *argument*, and parses that. The caller is responsible for providing that object, whether by creating a `StringIO` object, or using `with open(obj.yaml_path) as f: obj.load_yaml_config(f)`, or some other option.

Comment: @chepner thanks for your answer! Sorry about the newbie question: what happens with the original 'r' for read mode? I could I pass that as an argument?

Comment: `'r'` (`'rt'`, really) is the default mode, so it can be omitted. The only time I use it explicitly is when opening a file in binary mode, like `open(binfile, 'rb')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Out of curiosity, for my future testings, what could be done in case it was 'rb', or 'w'?

Comment: *chepner* is correct, I'm just not sure if dependency injection is a suitable pattern for `load_yaml_config()`. This method doesn't do anything except opening a file :) It becomes useless if caller opens the file. At that point the caller can just `with open(obj.yaml_path) as f: yaml.safe_load(f)`

Comment: @Expurple apologies for my ignorance, but what would "obj" stand for here? Could you please edit your answer to show that option? I would really appreciate it as it would help me a lot in understanding the concept.

Comment: @banana_99 I took `obj` from *chepner*'s comment above. It's an instance of the class from your post (the one that has `yaml_path` and `load_yaml_config()`)

Comment: Pretty sure you'd want to using `mock.patch` on the `open` function rather than just assigning to it.

Comment: But +++ for "create the appropriate yaml file in your testing code".  This is by far the easier method and is also a far better test of whether your code works as you expect.

Comment: @Expurple `load_yaml_confg` does *three* things: it opens a file, it reads from the file, and uses `yaml.load` to parse what is read. Moving the open outside the method still leaves it to read and parse. I'm comfortable with keeping reading and parsing as two discrete operations, even if `yaml.load` can read from a file-like object itself, and I also OK with `load_yaml_config` being a thin wrapper around `yaml.load` if that means you can post-process the configuration before returning it in the future.